# Showing that $\inf(r,s)=r\;\;\forall\;\;r,s\in \Re\;\;\text{and}\;\;s> r$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, supremum-and-infimum

> Prove that $\inf(r,s)=r,\;\;\forall\;\;r,s\in \Re\;\;\text{and}\;\;s> r$

I tried proving the above but got stuck. Here is what I've done!

Set $\text{S}=(r,s)$, then

$$(i.)\;\;r<x\;\;\forall \;\;x\in \text{S} ,$$

$$(ii.)\;\;\text{Let}\;\;\epsilon>0 \;\;\text{be given. We want to find } $$

$$s_{\epsilon}\in \text{S}\;\;:\;\;r\leq s_{\epsilon}<r+\epsilon.$$

We may choose

$$s_{\epsilon}=r+\frac{\epsilon}{2},\;\;\text{if}\;\;\epsilon\leq s-r,\;\;\text{or}$$

$$=\text{any fixed }\;x_{0}\in \text{S}, \text{otherwise}.$$

Please, I'm I on track? If yes, can anyone help me complete the proof? This choice of $s_{\epsilon}$ does not interest me either! I'll love if someone can give a better choice of $s_{\epsilon}$. Various kinds of proofs are welcome!

Comment: What are r and/or s. And what does inf(,) mean? Define it, then one might be able to answer the question.

Comment: Despite the missing links, from the context, it's clear that $S = (r,s)$ and OP wants to prove $\inf S = r$.

Comment: What makes you think your proof is not complete yet?

Comment: @  H. Gutsche: I'll edit it!

Comment: What is $s$ with respect to $r$? The question makes little sense without this information. If they can be any two real numbers then the result is wrong.

Comment: @  Eric Wofsey: It's because I don't understand this line $s_{\epsilon}=r+\frac{\epsilon}{2},\;\;\text{if}\;\;\epsilon\leq s-r.$

Comment: @  Arnaud Mortier: I've just edited it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We call $inf(r,s)=i$ if $i\in(r,s)$ then $\exists i' \in(r,i)$ .But then $i'<i$ which is not true.
If $i\in (-\infty,r)$ then r does not exist in $(r,s)$. But  we can find a greater bound $i''\in(i,r)$ also a contradiction.

Comment: @ DR.X: I'm trying to understand your proof! Can you please, break it down? Moreso, what's your conclusion? Thank you!

Comment: @ DR.X: I'm so sorry for the downvote! I didn't do it!

Comment: @ DR.X: I've raised it!

Comment: Do not worry for the votes .Thank you though. Lets break it down.
We know that   $inf(r,s)<x  \forall x\in (r,s)$ .Then $i$ cannot be in $(r,+\infty)$ because we could find  $a\in (r,inf) \cap (r,s)$ and then $a<inf$ and would be in $(r,s)$ a contradiction.
At the other hand if $i \in (-\infty,r)$ then we can find $i''\in(i,r)$  .
So $i''$ is a greater lower bound than $i$ which is contradiction

Comment: @  DR.X: Thank you very much for this!